# Keras accuracy does not change

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, theano, keras

I have a few thousand audio files and I want to classify them using Keras and Theano. So far, I generated a 28x28 spectrograms (bigger is probably better, but I am just trying to get the algorithm work at this point) of each audio file and read the image into a matrix. So in the end I get this big image matrix to feed into the network for image classification.

In a tutorial I found this mnist classification code:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils

batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 10
nb_epochs = 2

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
X_train = X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

print(X_train.shape[0], "train samples")
print(X_test.shape[0], "test samples")

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
y_test =  np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(output_dim = 100, input_dim = 784, activation= "relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 200, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 200, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim = nb_classes, activation = "softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy")

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epochs, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 2, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 0)
print("Test score: ", score[0])
print("Test accuracy: ", score[1])
```

This code runs, and I get the result as expected:

```
(60000L, 'train samples')
(10000L, 'test samples')
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/2
2s - loss: 0.2988 - acc: 0.9131 - val_loss: 0.1314 - val_acc: 0.9607
Epoch 2/2
2s - loss: 0.1144 - acc: 0.9651 - val_loss: 0.0995 - val_acc: 0.9673
('Test score: ', 0.099454972004890438)
('Test accuracy: ', 0.96730000000000005)
```

Up to this point everything runs perfectly, however when I apply the above algorithm to my dataset, accuracy gets stuck.

My code is as follows:

```
import os

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.utils import np_utils

import AudioProcessing as ap
import ImageTools as it

batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 2
nb_epoch = 10  


for i in range(20):
    print "\n"
# Generate spectrograms if necessary
if(len(os.listdir("./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Image")) > 0):
    print "Audio files are already processed. Skipping..."
else:
    print "Generating spectrograms for the audio files..."
    ap.audio_2_image("./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Audio/","./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Image/",".wav",".png",(28,28))

# Read the result csv
df = pd.read_csv('./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Result/result.csv', header = None)

df.columns = ["RegionName","IsNormal"]

bool_mapping = {True : 1, False : 0}

nb_classes = 2

for col in df:
    if(col == "RegionName"):
        a = 3      
    else:
        df[col] = df[col].map(bool_mapping)

y = df.iloc[:,1:].values

y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, nb_classes)

# Load images into memory
print "Loading images into memory..."
X = it.load_images("./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Image/",".png")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 784)
X_train = X_train.astype("float32")
X_test = X_test.astype("float32")
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

print("X_train shape: " + str(X_train.shape))
print(str(X_train.shape[0]) + " train samples")
print(str(X_test.shape[0]) + " test samples")

model = Sequential()


model.add(Dense(output_dim = 100, input_dim = 784, activation= "relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 200, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim = 200, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim = nb_classes, activation = "softmax"))

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam")

print model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epoch, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 1, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 1)
print("Test score: ", score[0])
print("Test accuracy: ", score[1])
```

AudioProcessing.py

```
import os
import scipy as sp
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
import Image

def save_spectrogram_scipy(source_filename, destination_filename, size):
    dt = 0.0005
    NFFT = 1024       
    Fs = int(1.0/dt)  
    fs, audio = wav.read(source_filename)
    if(len(audio.shape) >= 2):
        audio = sp.mean(audio, axis = 1)
    fig = pylab.figure()    
    ax = pylab.Axes(fig, [0,0,1,1])    
    ax.set_axis_off()
    fig.add_axes(ax) 
    pylab.specgram(audio, NFFT = NFFT, Fs = Fs, noverlap = 900, cmap="gray")
    pylab.savefig(destination_filename)
    img = Image.open(destination_filename).convert("L")
    img = img.resize(size)
    img.save(destination_filename)
    pylab.clf()
    del img

def audio_2_image(source_directory, destination_directory, audio_extension, image_extension, size):
    nb_files = len(os.listdir(source_directory));
    count = 0
    for file in os.listdir(source_directory):
        if file.endswith(audio_extension):        
            destinationName = file[:-4]
            save_spectrogram_scipy(source_directory + file, destination_directory + destinationName + image_extension, size)
            count += 1
            print ("Generating spectrogram for files " + str(count) + " / " + str(nb_files) + ".")
```

ImageTools.py

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
def load_images(source_directory, image_extension):
    image_matrix = []
    nb_files = len(os.listdir(source_directory));
    count = 0
    for file in os.listdir(source_directory):
        if file.endswith(image_extension):
            with open(source_directory + file,"r+b") as f:
                img = mpimg.imread(f)
                img = img.flatten()                
                image_matrix.append(img)
                del img
                count += 1
                #print ("File " + str(count) + " / " + str(nb_files) + " loaded.")
    return np.asarray(image_matrix)
```

So I run the above code and recieve:

```
Audio files are already processed. Skipping...
Loading images into memory...
X_train shape: (2394L, 784L)
2394 train samples
1027 test samples
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initial input shape: (None, 784)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Layer (name)                  Output Shape                  Param #
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dense (dense)                 (None, 100)                   78500
Dense (dense)                 (None, 200)                   20200
Dense (dense)                 (None, 200)                   40200
Dense (dense)                 (None, 2)                     402
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total params: 139302
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
None
Train on 2394 samples, validate on 1027 samples
Epoch 1/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6898 - acc: 0.5455 - val_loss: 0.6835 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 2/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6879 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6901 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 3/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6880 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6842 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 4/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6883 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6829 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 5/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6885 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6836 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 6/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6887 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6832 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 7/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6882 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6859 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 8/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6882 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6849 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 9/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6885 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6836 - val_acc: 0.5716
Epoch 10/10
2394/2394 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6877 - acc: 0.5522 - val_loss: 0.6849 - val_acc: 0.5716
1027/1027 [==============================] - 0s
('Test score: ', 0.68490593621422047)
('Test accuracy: ', 0.57156767283349563)
```

I tried changing the network, adding more epochs, but I always get the same result no matter what. I don't understand why I am getting the same result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
I found a mistake where pixel values were not read correctly. I fixed the ImageTools.py below as:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread

def load_images(source_directory, image_extension):
    image_matrix = []
    nb_files = len(os.listdir(source_directory));
    count = 0
    for file in os.listdir(source_directory):
        if file.endswith(image_extension):
            with open(source_directory + file,"r+b") as f:
                img = imread(f)                
                img = img.flatten()                        
                image_matrix.append(img)
                del img
                count += 1
                #print ("File " + str(count) + " / " + str(nb_files) + " loaded.")
    return np.asarray(image_matrix)
```

Now I actually get grayscale pixel values from 0 to 255, so now my dividing it by 255 makes sense. However, I still get the same result.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the optimizer is not suited to your dataset. Here is a list of [Keras optimizers](http://keras.io/optimizers/) from the documentation.

I recommend you first try SGD with default parameter values. If it still doesn't work, divide the learning rate by 10. Do that a few times if necessary. If your learning rate reaches 1e-6 and it still doesn't work, then you have another problem.

In summary, replace this line:

```
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam")
```

with this:

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt)
```

and change the learning rate a few times if it doesn't work.

If it was the problem, you should see the loss getting lower after just a few epochs.

Comment: When I tried 10^-5, accuracy became 0.53, and at 10^-6 it became 0.43. The rest was the same 0.57. Also I tried the other optimizers in your link, however the result was the same.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to change how you normalize your data. Try scikit-learn StandardScaler. If it still doesn't work, you will need a more complex model.

Comment: Yes, but it's not an RNN, just a few fully-connected layers.

Comment: StandardScaler does not work also. What kind of a more complex model should I try?

Comment: Recurrent Neural Networks usually gives good results with sequential data, like audio. See the Keras example on RNN and LSTM.

Comment: To get SGD working you have to include: from keras.optimizers import SGD

Comment: What is the possible reason for adam not suitable for the data?

Comment: I changed my lr = 1e-5 and my problem is solved. Hope this help!

Answer (score 17):

Another solution that I do not see mentioned here, but caused a similar problem for me was the activiation function of the last neuron, especialy if it is `relu` and not something non linear like `sigmoid`.

In other words, it might help you to **use a non-linear activation function in the last layer**

Last layer:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
```

Output:

```
7996/7996 [==============================] - 1s 76us/sample - loss: 6.3474 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 2/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 58us/sample - loss: 6.3473 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 3/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 58us/sample - loss: 6.3473 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 4/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 57us/sample - loss: 6.3473 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 5/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 58us/sample - loss: 6.3473 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 6/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 6.3473 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 7/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 57us/sample - loss: 6.3473 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 8/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 57us/sample - loss: 6.3473 - accuracy: 0.5860
```

Now I used a non linear activation function:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Output:

```
7996/7996 [==============================] - 1s 74us/sample - loss: 0.7663 - accuracy: 0.5899
Epoch 2/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 59us/sample - loss: 0.6243 - accuracy: 0.5860
Epoch 3/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 56us/sample - loss: 0.5399 - accuracy: 0.7580
Epoch 4/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 56us/sample - loss: 0.4694 - accuracy: 0.7905
Epoch 5/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 57us/sample - loss: 0.4363 - accuracy: 0.8040
Epoch 6/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 0.4139 - accuracy: 0.8099
Epoch 7/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 58us/sample - loss: 0.3967 - accuracy: 0.8228
Epoch 8/30
7996/7996 [==============================] - 0s 61us/sample - loss: 0.3826 - accuracy: 0.8260
```

*This is not directly a solution to the original answer, but as the answer is #1 on Google when searching for this problem, it might benefit someone.*

Answer (score 12):

If the accuracy is not changing, it means the optimizer has found a local minimum for the loss. This may be an undesirable minimum. One common local minimum is to  always predict the class with the most number of data points. You should use weighting on the classes to avoid this minimum.

```
from sklearn.utils import compute_class_weight
classWeight = compute_class_weight('balanced', outputLabels, outputs) 
classWeight = dict(enumerate(classWeight))
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epochs, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 2, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), class_weight=classWeight)
```

Answer (score 9):

After some examination, I found that the issue was the data itself. It was very dirty as in same input had 2 different outputs, hence creating confusion. After clearing up the data now my accuracy goes up to %69. Still not enough to be good, but at least I can now work my way up from here now that the data is clear.

I used the below code to test:

```
import os
import sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.utils import np_utils

sys.path.append("./")
import AudioProcessing as ap
import ImageTools as it


# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28
dim = 1
# number of convolutional filters to use
nb_filters = 32
# size of pooling area for max pooling
nb_pool = 2
# convolution kernel size
nb_conv = 3

batch_size = 128
nb_classes = 2
nb_epoch = 200

for i in range(20):
    print "\n"

## Generate spectrograms if necessary
if(len(os.listdir("./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Image")) > 0):
    print "Audio files are already processed. Skipping..."
else:
    # Read the result csv
    df = pd.read_csv('./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Result/AudioNormalPathalogicClassification_result.csv', header = None, encoding = "utf-8")

    df.columns = ["RegionName","Filepath","IsNormal"]

    bool_mapping = {True : 1, False : 0}

    for col in df:
        if(col == "RegionName" or col == "Filepath"):
            a = 3      
        else:
            df[col] = df[col].map(bool_mapping)

    region_names = df.iloc[:,0].values
    filepaths = df.iloc[:,1].values
    y = df.iloc[:,2].values
    #Generate spectrograms and make a new CSV file
    print "Generating spectrograms for the audio files..."
    result = ap.audio_2_image(filepaths, region_names, y, "./AudioNormalPathalogicClassification/Image/", ".png",(img_rows,img_cols))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = result)
    df.to_csv("NormalVsPathalogic.csv",header= False, index = False, encoding = "utf-8")

# Load images into memory
print "Loading images into memory..."
df = pd.read_csv('NormalVsPathalogic.csv', header = None, encoding = "utf-8")
y = df.iloc[:,0].values
y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, nb_classes)
y = np.asarray(y)

X = df.iloc[:,1:].values
X = np.asarray(X)
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], dim, img_rows, img_cols)
X = X.astype("float32")
X /= 255

print X.shape

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(64, nb_conv, nb_conv,
                        border_mode='valid',
                        input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, nb_conv, nb_conv))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta')

print model.summary()

model.fit(X, y, batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epoch, show_accuracy = True, verbose = 1)
```

Comment: It was very dirty as in same input had 2 different outputs, hence creating confusion -> What do you mean? that is **confusion**

Comment: I meant as in there was an error in labeling of the data. Same some of the inputs that are supposed to be marked as 1, were marked as 0.

Comment: @MuratAykanat Try increasing your # of epochs much more, like 1000 or 5000

Comment: @MuratAykanat, why did you use `softmax` activation in your last layer here:
`model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))`
Isn't it should be `sigmoid` if you have 2 classes only?

Comment: @bit_scientist if you change the last activation to sigmoid, you would also need to change the last dense layer to only have 1 neuron.  That would give some improvement, although it would be very small.  And it would be wise to leave the code as is if there is ever the possibility of reusing the code with more than 2 classes.

Answer (score 9):

Check out this one

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile( loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
               optimizer = sgd, 
               metrics=['accuracy']
             )
```

Check out the  [documentation](https://keras.io/optimizers/)

I had better results with MNIST

Answer (score 5):

By mistake I had added a softmax at the end instead of sigmoid. Try doing the latter. It worked as expected when I did this. For one output layer, softmax always gives values of 1 and this is what had happened.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue. One-hot encoding the target variable using nputils in Keras, solved the issue of accuracy and validation loss being stuck. Using weights for balancing the target classes further improved performance.

**Solution :**

```
from keras.utils.np.utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_val = to_categorical(y_val)
```

Comment: Paste the snippet in post would be good instead of image link.

Answer (score 3):

I've the same problem as you 
my solution was a loop instead of epochs

```js
for i in range(10):
  history = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=6,
                    epochs=1)
```

and you can as well save the model each epoch so you can pause the training after any epoch you want

```js
for i in range(10):
  history = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=6,
                    epochs=1)
  #save model
  model.save('drive/My Drive/vggnet10epochs.h5')
  model = load_model('drive/My Drive/vggnet10epochs.h5')
```

Answer (score 3):

I got 13% Accuracy increment using this 'sigmoid' activation

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3072, input_shape=(3072,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

Or you can also test the following, where 'relu' in first and hidden layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3072, input_shape=(3072,), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, the problem mainly arises from the type of optimizers chosen. However, it can also be driven from the fact of topping 2 Dense layers with the same activation functions(softmax, for example).
In this case, NN finds a local minimum and is not able to descent more from that point, rolling around the same acc (val_acc) values.
Hope it helps out.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I had binary class which was labeled by 1 and 2. After testing different kinds of optimizer and activation functions I found that the root of the problem was my labeling to classes. In the other words I changed the labels to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2, then this problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem for multi-class, Try to changing optimizer by default it is **Adam** change it to **sgd**.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

you can also try different **Activation functions** eg. (relu, sigmoid, softmax, softplus, etc.)

Some imp links

[Optimizers](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/)

[Activations](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, the optimizer probably doesn't suit your data/model which stuck in local minima. A neural network should at least be able to overfit the data (training_acc close to 1).
I once had a similar problem. I solved by trying different optimizers (in my case from SGD to RMSprop)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my problem was binary and I was using the 'softmax' activation function and it doesn't work. I changed to 'sigmoid' it works properly for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem: validation loss and accuracy remaining the same through the epochs.  I increased the batch size 10x times, reduced learning rate by 100x times, etc.  It did not work.

My last try, inspired by monolingual's and Ranjab's answers, worked.

my solution was to add Batchnormalization AND arrange the order as below:

Conv - DropOut - BatchNorm - Activation - Pool.

as recommended in [Ordering of batch normalization and dropout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691902/ordering-of-batch-normalization-and-dropout).

Answer (score 1):

Experienced same thing recently, did extensive research. Turns out that accuracy stuck at exact same value is due to your function stuck at bottom of local minima. It can be due to 2 reasons.

1. Optimizer selection
2. Unbalanced dataset

If dataset is unbalanced and model is stuck at bottom of local minima, it will keep predicting class with most number of images/data points. Try changing optimizers or try to make dataset balanced. It will solve problem in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but as of today (14/06/2021), the comment from @theTechGuy works well on tf 2.3. The code is:

```
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

    model.compile( loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
                   optimizer = sgd, 
                   metrics=['accuracy']
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing a lot with the optimizers and activation functions, but the only thing that worked was Batchnormalization[1](https://machinelearningmastery.com/batch-normalization-for-training-of-deep-neural-networks/). And I guess it is a good practice too.
You can import it as:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

and simply add it before each hidden layer:

```
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case, it was caused by a non-regularized column on my data. This column had huge value. Fixing that solved it for me.

So, I just converted it to values around 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to change the last layer activation function from "softmax" to "sigmoid" since i was dealing with a binary classification problem.

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```