# Keras mixed model gives same result in every epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have created a mixed model with text and image. When i train my model i get same results in every epochs. Below is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

base_dir = "D:/Dataset/xxxx/datasets/xxx/xx/xxxxx/"

import os

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,"trin.jsonl")
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,"tst.jsonl")
dev_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,"dv.jsonl")

df_train = pd.read_json(train_dir,lines=True)
df_test = pd.read_json(test_dir,lines=True)
df_dev = pd.read_json(dev_dir,lines=True)

df_train=df_train.set_index('id')
df_dev=df_dev.set_index('id')
df_test=df_test.set_index('id')

from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import re
import spacy
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

label_map = {1:"Hate",0:"No_Hate"}
df_dev['label']=df_dev['label'].map(label_map)
df_train['label']=df_train['label'].map(label_map)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_train,directory=img_path,x_col="img",y_col="label",target_size=(224,224),batch_size=8500,class_mode="binary",shuffle=False)

def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    sentence = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"," ",sentence)
    sentence_list = [word.lemma_ for word in nlp(sentence) if not (word.is_space or word.is_stop or len(word)==1)]
    return ' '.join(sentence_list)
    
image_files = pd.Series(train_generator.filenames)
image_files = image_files.str.split('/', expand=True)[1].str[:-4]
image_files = list(map(int, image_files))

df_sorted = df_train.reindex(image_files)
df_sorted.head(1)

images,labels = next(train_generator)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_sorted['new_text'].values)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_sorted['new_text'].values)
train_padd = pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=maxlen,padding='post',truncating='post')

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Embedding,Dropout,SpatialDropout1D,Conv1D,MaxPooling1D,GRU,BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Bidirectional,GlobalAveragePooling1D,GlobalMaxPooling1D,concatenate,LeakyReLU

def create_nlp():
    sequence_input=Input(shape=(maxlen))
    embedding_layer=Embedding(input_dim=text_embedding.shape[0],output_dim=text_embedding.shape[1],weights=[text_embedding],input_length=maxlen,trainable=False)
    embedded_sequence = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    l_conv_1=Conv1D(128,5,activation='relu')(embedded_sequence)
    l_pool_1=MaxPooling1D(5)(l_conv_1)
    l_conv_2=Conv1D(128,5,activation='relu')(l_pool_1)
    l_pool_2=MaxPooling1D(5)(l_conv_2)
    l_flat = Flatten()(l_pool_2)
    model=Model(sequence_input,l_flat)
    return model
    
    
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

def create_img():
    img_input=Input(shape=(224,224,3))
    conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    conv_base.trainable = False
    conv_l_1=conv_base(img_input)
    flat_l = Flatten()(conv_l_1)
    dense_l = Dense(256,activation='relu')(flat_l)
    model = Model(img_input,dense_l)
    return model

nlp_1=create_nlp()
img_cnn=create_img()
combinedInput = concatenate([nlp_1.output, img_cnn.output])

x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(combinedInput)
x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model1 = Model(inputs=[nlp_1.input, img_cnn.input], outputs=x)
opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model1.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['acc'], optimizer=opt)

model1_history = model1.fit([train_padd, images], train_y, epochs=15, batch_size=16)
```

Below is my training results:

```
Epoch 1/15
532/532 [==============================] - 104s 196ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 2/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 193ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 3/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 195ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 4/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 194ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 5/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 194ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 6/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 194ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 7/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 194ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 8/15
532/532 [==============================] - 104s 195ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 9/15
532/532 [==============================] - 106s 200ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 10/15
532/532 [==============================] - 109s 204ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 11/15
532/532 [==============================] - 104s 196ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 12/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 194ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 13/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 194ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 14/15
532/532 [==============================] - 104s 195ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
Epoch 15/15
532/532 [==============================] - 103s 193ms/step - loss: 0.6528 - acc: 0.6412
```

Also i am getting below logs in my terminal:

> Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.36GiB
> with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a
> failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more
> memory were available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213388/keras-accuracy-does-not-change), you might simply use improper optimizer. If that doesn't help, I would try to use 1 as batch size, to see if at least within first runs there is a change. As well the learning rate might be a problem, try to play with its value and see if the accuracy changes.

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Can you help me with one more thing. Do you know if there exist something like imagedatagenerator for text. It would really help me to train model with fit_generator and the memory issue can be resolved.